# Update the visible binding made in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have just started to learn Knockout, and have an interesting sitaution.

I have a "wizard" with three steps. Depending on choices made in step 1 and step 2, different things should show in step 3.

I made a function in Knockout:

```
self.canSendLetter = ko.computed(function () {
    console.log('Inside canSendLetter');
    if (self.priceStatus == "success") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

In my frontend I have tried the following with two databindings:

```
<input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submitAbe" value="@ViewRes.StampAndSendLetter &raquo;" data-bind="visible: canSendLetter(), click: save" />
```

I can see that the "inside candsendletter" is being logged when I load the page. However, I need this "visible binding" to update, when I go to step 3 in my wizard.

Currently I have the following code in goToStepThree:

```
 self.goToStepThree = function () {
        if (self.uploadPdf() == 1 && self.uploadFileKey() == '') {
            self.showMissingUpload(true);
            return false;
        } else if (self.writeContentEditor.getData() == '') {
            self.showMissingWriteContent(true);
            return false;
        }

        var thiz = self;
        var writtenContent = encodeURIComponent(self.htmlEncode(self.writeContentEditor.getData()));
        $.ajax({
            url: self.getPriceUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                usePdf: self.uploadPdf() == 1 ? 'true' : 'false',
                uploadFileKey: self.uploadFileKey(),
                content: writtenContent,
                address: self.address(),
                postal: self.postal(),
                city: self.city(),
                country: self.country()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                thiz.priceStatus = data.status;
                thiz.priceStatusMessage = data.message;
                thiz.cost(data.price);
                thiz.numberOfPages(data.numberOfPages);
                if (data.isAuthenticated) {
                    self.isAuthenticated(true);
                    self.isValidCredits(data.isValidCredits);
                    self.paymentMethod('Credits (' + data.credits + '$ left)');
                }

                thiz.currentStep(3);

            }
        });
    };
```

So my question is:

How do I make sure my btnsubmit button, is calling the canSendLetter function when I go to step three?

**EDIT**:

My viewmodel:

I defined the priceStatus and priceStatusMessage as observables here:

```
 self.priceStatus = ko.observable('');
    self.priceStatusMessage = ko.observable('');
```

Comment: Turn `priceStatus` into an observable instead of a plain value. The `visible` binding will be recomputed when the value of `priceStatus` changes.

Comment: You haven't shown us your full code. Please include the other relevant details too, give us a short repro.

Comment: Change `thiz.priceStatus = data.status;` to `thiz.priceStatus(data.status);` and `self.priceStatus == "success"` to `self.priceStatus() == "success"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! @haim770 can you make an answer? then I will mark it as a solution.
Your answer actually helped me understand more about how Knockout works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `priceStatus` field is indeed an `observable`, yet it has to be used appropriately:

When comparing it's value (getter):

```
self.canSendLetter = ko.computed(function () {
    console.log('Inside canSendLetter');
    return self.priceStatus() === "success";
});
```

And when settings it's value (setter):

```
success: function (data) {
         thiz.priceStatus(data.status);
         thiz.priceStatusMessage(data.message);
         ...
         }
```

Knockout has no way to get notified when some data on your ViewModel is changed, the only way is to go through the `observable` mechanism that is able to 'notify subscribers' (like your `canSendLetter` computed).

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Comment: Helped a lot :-) Thanks